# How can I create Angular 2 custom attribute directive with dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create custom attribute directive in the same manner how it is done for built-in directives like "attr", "class", "style" used as in this example:

```
<div [style.width.px]="mySize">
```

The documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) describes only the case with a fixed directive name. So the questions are:

1. How should I specify selector for such directive?
2. How can I retrieve the variable part of the directive name?

Or may be it is not possible at all and used only for built-in directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it's almost certainely not possible to do this as inspected by @Günter as well.

---

[**PLUNKER ⇗**](http://plnkr.co/edit/umikdXtMctH3g34iFBab?p=preview)

But if you just want a directive that works almost similarly to the `style`, this might help you.

**Usage:**

```ts
<h2 [customStyle]="['width.px', mysize]" >Hello {{name}}</h2>
```

**Custom Directive:**

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[customStyle]',
  inputs: ['style:customStyle']
})
export class CustomDir{
  style;
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef){
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    if(this.style){
      const prop = this.style[0].split('.')[0];
      const unit = this.style[0].split('.')[1];
      const val  = this.style[1];

      this.elRef.nativeElement.style[prop] = val + (unit || '');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple of customStyle attributes in one tag like with style.* binding?

Comment: unfortunately NO. but you can always modify it to accept more than one styling just like `ngStyle`

Comment: One more question. Why setTimeout() is needed  your code?

Comment: Oh I left it there by mistake, initially I was using OnInit hook where manual change detection trigger is required, but now it's not. sorry, removing..

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported and also not planned as far as I know.

> Or may be it is not possible at all and used only for built-in directives?

This syntax is not related to directives, it is built-in binding syntax.